# Is there a way to have a temporary data store?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I need to do a bunch of model manipulation as a series of operations that can individually fail, but I want to make the entire manipulations atomic: if any of those operations fail, I want the data store to be left untouched, as it was before the operation. If they all succeed, I want the data store to reflect the new state.

With CoreData (iOS/Mac), I am used to doing this by creating a child `NSManagedObjectContext` and performing my updates in this child context. If manipulation operations succeed, I save the child context to propagate the updates into the main context. If not, I simply discard the child context.

Is there any similar mechanism available in Ember Data?

Comment: I think the way forward is for you to create your own "ManagedObjectContext".

Comment: If you know which models may have been touched, then call `rollbackAttributes` on all of them if the overall operation fails.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the details of what types of data are on the model, how it got there and how it will be transformed make it hard to answer well.

One really broad solution (that assumes you don't need computed properties and all that would be to:

1. `toJSON` your model to a new variable. Make sure to include the id[api docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_toJSON)
2. ...Do your manipulation...
3. `store.push()` the new json. It should update the model if the id's are the same [api docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_push)